# My NetBeans is showing my GUI chars cut and disappear

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

Every time I run certain GUI interface excercises using swing the program works perfectly but something is wrong with what I suspect might be the jdk or something as it also happens like this on Eclypse.

It first appears to show correctly but with mouse over or when entering data in a textfield it all shows distorted.

Has anyone encountered these problems?

Comment: What exercises do you run? Swing applications you have written yourself? Or is the netbeans ui itself distorted? Could also be a problem with your OS/graphics driver. You have to provide more detail (OS type and version, JDK version etc.), and perhaps ask somewhere else (like in a forum for your OS).

Comment: *"Every time I run certain GUI interface excercises.."*  The code is broken.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: They are exercises from an online course, they give me the code. The code is not the issue as I have tried on other computers and work.

I Have an alienware set up for extreme gaming. Graphics card should not be a problem unless its a compatibility issue with GUI. I would find this quite weird....

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem re-installing the drivers to my graphics card!

Thank you.

Hope this helps anyone in the future with the same issue